# Copy root file system to the USB

Tags: filesystems

I have an embedded debian image for emtrion am335. I finished with the development phase. I have my root file system working only one board. My aim is to deploy this root file system to other boards. Basically want to copy all files in development board to other boards using filezilla.

I tried these steps as `root`below,

1. `mount the usb to the /mnt/my_filesystem`
2. `sudo chmod 777 /mnt/my_filesystem`
3. `cp -ax / /mnt/my_filesystem`

After all these i get operation not permitted error.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: I would advice not to copy the root fs of a running system because it contains files and directories that only exist on a running system. Instead mount both the source and target partitions on another system and copy there. Maybe you could also copy the entire root partition.

Answer (score 0):

`cp` also requires `sudo` when copying an entire directory hierarchy. You haven't shown the errors you're getting which could simplify debugging and helping you, for instance `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/gshadow` are only readable by root.

Comment: He's already stated that he's run  the commands as root.